# I need help trying to call 3rd party api with authentication from node server

Tags: node.js, api, authentication

I am trying to call 2 3rd party apis. 1st to login and receive Bearer token and 2nd to post message.  1st works fine and I get the token. but when I try to call second api to post message it fails, probably because I dont know how to set the received token in 2nd api

here is my code

```js
var myJSONObject = {
    "email": auth[0],
    "password": auth[1]
};
req.post({
    url: "{{server_url}}/auth/login",
    method: "POST",
    json: true,
    body: myJSONObject
}, function (error, res, body){
    if(error){
        console.log(error.message);
    } else {
        var myJSONObject1 = {    
            "category":"SYSTEM",
            "type": "ALERT",
            "keywords":"FUNCTION|createSomethingLvl1",
            "status":"UNREAD",
            "from": "tenantadmin@tenantadmin.com",
            "to": "someemail@gmail.com",
            "subject": "Some nice subject",
            "body": "Some detailed body that contains information that informs the person" 
     };

        req.post({
            url: "{{server_url}}/api/message",
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": res.body.access_token,
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
            json: true,
            body: myJSONObject1
        }, function (err, res1, body){
            if(error){
                console.log(err.message);
            } else {
                console.log(res1.body); 
            }                    
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Authorization needs the word "bearer" in front of the token.

Comment: Bearer is already inside res.body.access_token

Answer (score 1):

If this is a "typical" http bearer token, then you need the word "Bearer" in front of the token like this:

```
"Authorization": "Bearer " + res.body.access_token,
```

You can see examples of a Bearer token in the [OAuth RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) where it shows the grammar as:

```
b64token    = 1*( ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~" / "+" / "/" ) *"="
"Bearer" 1*SP b64token
```

And, here's an example from a [Google API doc](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/actions/verifying-bearer-tokens):

```
Authorization: Bearer AbCdEf123456
```

And, another example from an [OAuth doc](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer-13.xml):

```
Authorization: Bearer vF9dft4qmT
```